# How to get number of calls per x made to AWS API Gateway using CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to get metrics that show how many calls were made to our APIs (on API Gateway) in a given period of time.  I'm using CloudWatch.  There is a metric called Count, which AWS documentation says is "The total number API requests in a given period."  But it only ever comes to 1, whether the given period is 1 minutes, 5 minutes or 1 week.  It may well be that we never have 2 calls hit a given API at exactly the same point, so each API endpoint is only ever hit once, but what I want is if I have 10 people hitting my API endpoint 10 times each in 5 minutes then I am shown 100.  If I have 15 people hitting my API endpoint 10 times each in 10 minutes then I want to see 150.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

You now probably have the default (=Average) statistic selected. To see the total, you need to select Sum as the Statistic in the 'Graphed Metrics' tab.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you!!